# How can I disable the automatic translation of MS web pages?

Tags: website, translation

When visiting MS Knowledge base articles many are automatically translated (into Dutch).
I prefer the original English texts so that I don't have to second guess which Dutch terms the translator (human or machine) uses.

I'm using a Dutch Win7 OS with a Dutch Firefox browser.
No language or translation related add-ons are installed.

[This SuperUser artice is only about IE](https://superuser.com/questions/468710/how-do-i-disable-microsoft-translator-in-internet-explorer).
[This forum discussion](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/is/translator/thread/daa3774d-68c2-4bd6-ba6f-ea6ec53fadfc) suggests that it is a website (owner) decision, but is also IE oriented.
I do not want to disable all geolocation info [as suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/115536/keeping-websites-from-knowing-where-i-live), because it's fine when e.g. Google search results are tailored to my location.
[This article](http://www.bing.com/community/bingsearch/f/12244/p/678579/9689621.aspx) refers to an unreachable FAQ, searching for 'microsoft translation faq' gives me plenty of [info](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/help/) about the MS translation services, *except* how to disable it!

[Edited to add sep 2014]
I redirected `www.microsofttranslator.com` to 127.0.0.1 (and to ::1) in the hosts file but that does not block the translation.

Comment: +1 machine translated text is quite poor. Even though machine translation has made quite some progress, a technically versed human reader will do a better translation in his/her head than some algorithm. While machine translation might seem work well enough for literature, there it fails with regards to sayings, cultural associations, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is part of the Microsoft website, not Firefox.

They do offer a link to compare the translation to the original, and on that comparison page there is a link to the original text. You can circumvent it immediately by adding `/en-us`  to the web address.

- Take for example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192573
- add "/en-us"
- get: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192573/en-us

Note that translated pages not always tell you that they are, e.g. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192573 in the case of Dutch - but maybe that page was not **automatically** translated.

Added note 27 July 2016: Things have changed slightly but the trick still works. If I now go to `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192573`, I get `https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/kb/192573`. If I then append `/en-us`, this is again redirected to `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/192573`.

Comment: I (the OP) have taken the liberty of editing your answer because it is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to change your browser-wide preferred language setting, you can request English articles by default - without using extensions.

[Related StackOverflow answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20972981/227)

In case that one gets wiped: basically you need to change your language preference in your browser and move English to the top. MSDN and KB articles apparently respect the `Accept-Language` header sent by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each page, there's a language switcher, which I suppose is actually "Deutschland (Deutsch)" for you. If you set it to "United States (English)", it will never bother you again.

[image]

Comment: I know you are new to this site, but wanted to make you aware you are posting an answer to a 2-year old question that has an accepted answer already. There is nothing wrong with doing so, just realize it may not be responded to or accepted.

Comment: This looks like a new feature that was not there at the time I asked the question